# How to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 sqlite3 from 3.13 to new version 3.25

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu-18.04

I followed this article (system install section) to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 sqlite 3.13 to sqlite 3.25. The Ubuntu was upgraded from 14 to 18, and sqlite was installed 3 years ago.

http://charlesleifer.com/blog/compiling-sqlite-for-use-with-python-applications/

All steps are successful, but sqlite is still old version 3.13.

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.13.0'
```

It should be?

```
'3.25.0'
```

I also tried to remove sqlite 3.13 and reinstall, with commands in this article:

https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/sqlite3?type=uninstall

it can't be removed. Tried all remove commands, such as following, sqlite3 is still active:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge sqlite3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'sqlite3' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 115 not upgraded.
fake@fakedesktop1:~$ sqlite3 --version
3.13.0 2016-05-18 10:57:30 fc49f556e48970561d7ab6a2f24fdd7d9eb81ff2
```

I want to know how to upgrade sqlite3 to new version 3.25. What's wrong with my steps?

Comment: Why does your Python startup text say Redhat if you're on Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi Shawn, thank you for your reply. I installed anaconda on ubuntu 14 (upgrated to 18.04), and created few virtualenv. I am not sure if anaconda changes default python. Since all virtualenv worked as expected for me, I did not notice this. Do you think this matters?

Comment: I think my anaconda installation is not correct. I reinstalled anaconda3, Python shows no redhat anymore, then sqlite3 got upgraded to newer version.

Comment: might give you some info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/677528/can-sqlite3-be-upgraded-on-ubuntu